# jQuery geolocation form submit anomaly in Firefox / Windows 7

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, geolocation

The following code submits correctly in IE, Safari, Chrome on Mac and Windows, Firefox in Mac, but in Firefox (17.01) on Windows 7 the submitForm function is never called.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        if(navigator.geolocation)
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,submitForm); 
        else 
            submitForm();
    });
});

function success(locationData) {
    $("#lat").val(locationData.coords.latitude);
    $("#lng").val(locationData.coords.longitude);
    submitForm();
}

function submitForm() {
  alert('About to submit');
  $("#theForm").submit();
  return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="theForm" name="theForm" >
  <input type="text" id="lat" placeholder="Latitude" value="" />
  <input type="text" id="lng" placeholder="Longitude" value="" />
</form>
<button id="submit">OK</button>
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv28K/)

Comment: Try removing `return false;` from the `submitForm()` function.

Comment: Initially tried without, and added it in case it was the issue.  Doesn't work with or without

Comment: It seems to be working for me. I am on firefox with windows 7 [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv28K/13/)

Comment: Can you post your Windows and FF version. I cannot get the alert to fire which implies that the function is not being called

Comment: I am using FF 17.0.1 and Windows 7. It asks if I would like to share my location, and then pops up with an `alert about to submit` and then post to the page. I had to use the `post method` to get it to work.

Comment: There's a possibility it could be due to my FF config/plugins - testing now on another machine and will report back.

Comment: @BlakePlumb I could not replicate on the laptop which worked OK. Will be interested to hear if this works for others or whether this anomaly is isolated to my PC.

Comment: I have to do somewhat similar to this. But if the location values are in form fields, if i want to get these values accurately, users may alter these values to spoof. how to get ride this?